# *[SEVERE]* Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart. This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[WARNING] ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/gql_code_builder-0.2.0/lib/src/ast.dart:618:12: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Expression' doesn't allow null.

- 'Expression' is from 'package:code_builder/src/specs/expression.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/code_builder-4.1.0/lib/src/specs/expression.dart').
  Expression _directiveLocation(DirectiveLocation location) {
  ^
  [INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 838ms

[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.

Comment: post your  `pubspec.yaml` and `flutter -doctor` output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like here there is a fix [gql-dart/gql#308](https://github.com/gql-dart/gql/issues/308#issuecomment-1098179710)

```
dependency_overrides:
  gql: 0.13.0
```

Comment: Thank you @matteodg

Comment: This work only for gql package. In other cases it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try "flutter pub upgrade". This helped me.