# Unknown riverpod_generator error when running build_runner. ERROR: Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I had been practicing riverpod in flutter with *riverpod_generator* and everything was working fine.
The command `dart run build_runner watch -d` was also running perfectly and generating `.g.dart` files when suddenly something went wrong and I was being shown this error when running build runner:

```
user@name MINGW64 /a/flutter_code/aa
$ dart run build_runner build -v
[INFO] Entrypoint:Generating build script...
[INFO] Entrypoint:Generating build script completed, took 663ms

[INFO] Bootstrap:Precompiling build script......
[WARNING] Bootstrap:
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/functional_provider.dart:38:33: Error: The getter 
'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
    final returnType = provider.createdType;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/functional_provider.dart:61:48: Error: The getter 
'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
final $providerName = $providerType<${provider.valueType}>.internal(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/functional_provider.dart:69:50: Error: The getter 
'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
typedef $refName = ${providerType}Ref<${provider.valueType}>;
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/class_based_provider.dart:101:33: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
    final returnType = provider.createdType;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/class_based_provider.dart:115:66: Error: The getter 'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
final $providerName = $providerType<${provider.name}, ${provider.valueType}>.internal(
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/class_based_provider.dart:123:61: Error: The getter 'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
typedef $notifierTypedefName = $notifierBaseType<${provider.valueType}>;
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:55:32: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
    var createdType = provider.createdType.toString();
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:57:33: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
    final returnType = provider.createdType;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:65:44: Error: The getter 'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
        createdType = 'FutureOr<${provider.valueType}>';
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:90:38: Error: The getter 'valueType' isn't defined for the class 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'FunctionalProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
      providerGenerics: '<${provider.valueType}>',
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:134:33: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
    final returnType = provider.createdType;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:167:56: Error: The getter 'valueType' 
isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
      providerGenerics: '<${provider.name}, ${provider.valueType}>',
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:172:74: Error: The getter 'valueType' 
isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
abstract class $notifierTypedefName extends $notifierBaseType<${provider.valueType}> {
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:175:14: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
  ${provider.createdType} build($parameterDefinition);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:180:14: Error: The getter 'createdType' isn't defined for the class 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'ClassBasedProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'createdType'.
  ${provider.createdType} runNotifierBuild(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:248:45: Error: The getter 'exposedType' isn't defined for the class 'GeneratorProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'GeneratorProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'exposedType'.
class $familyName extends Family<${provider.exposedType}> {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_generator-2.3.4/lib/src/templates/family.dart:332:43: Error: The getter 'valueType' 
isn't defined for the class 'GeneratorProviderDeclaration'.
 - 'GeneratorProviderDeclaration' is from 'package:riverpod_analyzer_utils/src/riverpod_ast.dart' ('/C:/Users/user@name/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/riverpod_analyzer_utils-0.4.1/lib/src/riverpod_ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'valueType'.
mixin $refNameImpl on $refType<${provider.valueType}> {
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
[INFO] Bootstrap:Precompiling build script... completed, took 1.9s

[SEVERE] Bootstrap:
Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: aa
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: "none"
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.4 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.4
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  riverpod_generator: ^2.3.4
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  custom_lint: ^0.5.4
  riverpod_lint: ^2.0.2

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

What I have already tried:

- `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub cache clean` -> `dart run build_runner build clean`
- Trying previous working versions of all riverpod dependencies including dev dependencies
- Reinstalling flutter completely along with deleting *appdata/Local/Pub* folder; and updating platform-tools, sdk, etc from Android Studio.
- Multiple times tried to update dependencies `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`
- Been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76630409/when-i-try-to-run-my-flutter-project-it-shows-this-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962457/severe-failed-to-precompile-build-script-dart-tool-build-entrypoint-build-d)

It's been two days since I am stuck at this point and finding no solutions. Asking it here is last option for me. Kindly ask for any more info if needed and provide me the solution to start practicing again.

Comment: Remove the pinning of all of your riverpod-related things.  see if it comes up with a new solution.  If so, lock that in.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz tried it with both latest versions and versions from a working project, didn't work.

Comment: This looks like a mismatch with your dart or flutter SDK.  Did you try a prior SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *riverpod_generator* and *riverpod_lint* plugin's latest version (as of time of writing answer) is :

```
riverpod_generator: 2.3.4
riverpod_lint: 2.3.1
```

From the source provided by @MatthewWong, developer of riverpod himself claims that

> a breaking change landed in riverpod_analyzer_util with an incorrect
> version number bump.
> -Remi Rousselet [[source]](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2943#issuecomment-1743197918)

Therefore as of now, there are two workarounds:

1. As mentioned by @MatthewWong's source is to use:

   ```
   riverpod_generator: 3.0.0-dev.3 
   riverpod_lint: ^2.3.1
   ```

   If latest(working) dev release is required.
2. And if latest stable version is required, following version combination of both plugins are working fine:

   ```
   riverpod_generator: 2.3.3 
   riverpod_lint: 2.1.0
   ```

Till required changes are made in *riverpod_generator*, these workarounds are working well.
No Flutter SDK downgrades are required and the workaround is working fine with latest Dart and Flutter SDK versions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the latest versions of riverpod isn't working. This issue gives more context:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2943

EDIT: A workaround that worked for me was to use riverpod_generator 3.0.0-dev.3. See this comment: https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/3005#issuecomment-1766892690

Comment: your sources provide the right workaround and point out the right problem with the plugin. I have written an answer from whatever I have gathered so far. Thank you very much @MatthewWong.